# How do I perform a nested iteration?

Tags: julia

I defined a function `m(r,T,a,w)` and I have vectors for the variables `r,T,w.` 
What I want to do is to take the first element of each of those vectors and iterate my function `for a in 1:T`, then take the sum and repeat this iteration for the second element of those vectors and so on. 
In the end I want to have a vector consisting of all the sums.
I would appreciate your help.

What I tried so far:

(`W`,`R`,`LE` are the vectors for the variables for `w`,`r`,`T`, respectively)

```
M = []
for w in W, r in R, T in LE 
    for a in 1:T
    MM=sum(m(r,T,a,w))
    push!(M,MM)
end
end
```

clearly Julia would not recognise what Im trying to do

Comment: Please show the code you've already wrote trying to perform this task and describe what's your exact problem with that code.

Comment: thanks, I edited my post

Comment: "clearly Julia would not recognise what Im trying to do" What sort of issue exactly are you facing? Does the code crash, etc?

Comment: I still have absolutely no idea what you're asking about. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new to programming in general, my vectors `R,W,LE` are `52×1 DataArrays.DataArray{Any,2}`, however the vector `M`, I computed consists of 6086704 elements. I just dont know how to tell Julia to hold the first element of the vectors `R,W,LE`  fixed, then compute the sum of the iteration `for a in 1:T` and then go on to the second element of the vectors and compute the sum of the iteration `for a in 1:T` ...

Answer (score 4):

The syntax:

```
for w in W, r in R, T in LE
    ...
```

does not iterate over the vectors at the same time. Rather, it is equivalent to the product:

```
for w in W
    for r in R
        for T in LE
            ...
```

It sounds like you want to iterate over those three vectors at the same time.  In that case, you can use `zip`:

```
for (w,r,T) in zip(W,R,LE)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer is correct, but you might want to improve a few other things, such as the types, and putting this in a function so that it isn't using a global variable.  Do you know what the type of the sum is?  Would a `Float64` work, or a `Int64`?
For example:

```
function myfun(W, R, LE)
    M = Vector{Float64}()
    for (w, r, T) in zip(W, R, LE), a in T
        push!(M, sum(m(r, T, a, w)))
    end
    M
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the very helpful comments. I managed to code what I wanted

```
  MM = Vector{Float64}()
    M = Vector{Float64}()
    for (w, r, T) in zip(W, R, LE)
        for a in 1:T
          push!(MM, m(r,T,a,w))
        end
          push!(M,sum(MM))
    end
```